# What's the easiest way to create a pre-built "image" of a Debian/Rasbian host?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm playing around with my raspberry pi project and have made a number of customizations to my device OS (simple stuff... configuration files... installed packages... etc).

I would like to make a "copy" of my system available for others to download/use.  What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to make an image:

```
ssh root@raspberrypi cat /dev/sda >rpi.img
```

This creates a large raw copy. If you want to compress the file, you should first fill the unused disk space with a compressible pattern. Run this command in any on-disk directory (if you run multiple partitions, do it for it partition):

```
cat /dev/zero >zero; rm zero
```

To restore, `cat rpi.img >/dev/sda` after booting from some external media (replace `sda` by the right designation for the internal storage).

This is not necessarily the best way to make an image for an identical installation. If you only want to save your settings, you only need to back up a few things:

- `/etc` (`tar czf etc.tgz /etc`);
- the list of packages you've installed (see [Re-installing apps after a fresh install?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104333/re-installing-apps-after-a-fresh-install/104472#104472));
- The content of `/home`, `/root`, `/usr/local`, `/opt` if you put things there.

You can then restore an identical system by doing a minimal installation, restoring the packages (see [Re-installing apps after a fresh install?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104333/re-installing-apps-after-a-fresh-install/104472#104472)), and restoring `/etc` and other hierarchies. If you're sharing the installation over the Internet, this has the advantage that you only need to share a few megabytes, not a few gigabytes (the rest is downloaded from Debian/Raspbian's servers).

Answer (score 0):

Take the SD card out of your Raspberry. Insert it into a desktop computer's SD card reader. Under Linux it will show up as device, e.g. /dev/sdx. Use dmesg or hwinfo to find out the actual device name. Then [clone](http://www.linuxintro.org/wiki/Cloning#byte-by-byte_copy_2) it to a file e.g. using the command

```
dd if=/dev/sdx | bzip2 -z | cat >/var/www/image_file.bz2
```

Do not forget to adapt this line according to your needs; replace /dev/sdx by your device name and /var/www/image_file.bz2 by the name of the file you want to share.

Once other users have received image_file they can unpack it using bunzip and restore it [as usual](http://www.linuxintro.org/wiki/Dd#Restore_a_backup).